# How to write regex for an endpoint?

Tags: regex

I am writing a regex for this test string,

```
2021-11-25 17:04:48,015 INFO  [wso2/gateway/src/gateway/utils] - [BlockingConditionRetrievalTask] [-] Blocking condition retrieval successful. Stopping the timer task ...
```

here is the regex i got so far,

```
^\d{4}\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])* (?:[01]\d|2[0123]):(?:[012345]\d):(?:[012345]\d),\d{3} {1,2}(?<loglevel>[DEBUG\ INFO\ ERROR\ WARN][A-Z]*)\s
```

how to write the regex for the `[wso2/gateway/src/gateway/utils]` which is an endpoint and the `[BlockingConditionRetrievalTask]`

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```java
^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d+\s+(?<loglevel>[A-Z]+)\s+\[(?<logendpoint>[^\]\[]*)]\s+\S+\s+\[(?<logtask>[^\]\[]*)]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VSfd1Y/1/). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}` - date-like pattern
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d+` - time-like pattern
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(?<loglevel>[A-Z]+)` - Group "loglevel": one or more uppercase letters
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `\[` - a `[` char
- `(?<logendpoint>[^\]\[]*)` - Group "logendpoint": any zero or more chars other than `]` and `[`
- `]\s+\S+\s+\[` - `]`, one or more non-whitespaces enclosed with one or more whitespaces, and a `[` char
- `(?<logtask>[^\]\[]*)` - Group "logtask": any zero or more chars other than `]` and `[`
- `]` - a `]` char.